# Get data back from "select for xml raw"

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an query with select for xml raw statment. Result looks like

```
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />
```

or

```
<row UWI="123" Xcord="2.4" obj_id="1" err_id="1" /> 
<row UWI="122" Xcord="1.4"obj_id="1" err_id="2" />
```

and all xml stored in one cell. Each cell can have different attribute names and quantity.

I want to select it back from xml into table like

```
link____|DATASOURCE  |obj_id|err_id   
someLink|SomeSystem__|1____ |1

someLink|SomeSystem__|1____ |2
```

But node attributes are dynamic.

I can get list of id and values with

```
select 
   t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as [id],
   t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') as [value]
from @XMLVal.nodes('row/@*') as t(c)
```

## UPDATE

My solution

```
declare 
@colNames TABLE(
  id INT IDENTITY,
  colName nvarchar(max)
);
declare @XMLVal XML;
set @XMLVal = '<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />';
-----DEFINE COLUMN NAMES-------------
insert into @colNames
select distinct
       t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as [ID]
from @XMLVal.nodes('row/@*') as t(c) 
-----COUNT COLUMNS QNTY---------------------
DECLARE @MaxCount INT;
SELECT @MaxCount = count(*) from @colNames
-----GENERATE SQL---------------------------
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max), @i INT, @curentColumnName nvarchar(max);
SET @i = 0;
SET @SQL = 'declare @XMLVal XML;
SET @XMLVal = ''<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />'';
select ';
WHILE @i < @MaxCount
BEGIN
   SET @i = @i + 1;
     select @curentColumnName = colName from @colNames where id = @i;
     SET @SQL = @SQL + ' t.c.value(''@' + @curentColumnName + ''', ''nvarchar(128)'') as ' + @curentColumnName;
    if (@i < @MaxCount ) begin
       SET @SQL = @SQL + ', ';
    end 
 END
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' from @XMLVal.nodes(''/row'') as t(c)'; 
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier - in cases where you know your target in detail - to address the elements and attributes of an XML directly with an XPath.

Your approach is perfectly OK for generic reading of an unknown XML - but much to complicated here. You'd have to first read your attributes row-wise and then have to perform some kind of `PIVOT` or `GROUP BY with Max(CASE... )` to get them as plain table back.

Be aware, that your XML seems to have not root element. This is possible in SQL queries, but - strictly seen - not valid...

```
DECLARE @XMLVal XML=
'<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />';

select 
   t.c.value('@link', 'nvarchar(128)') as link,
   t.c.value('@DATASOURCE', 'nvarchar(128)') as DATASOURCE,
   t.c.value('@obj_id', 'int') as obj_id,
   t.c.value('@err_id', 'int') as err_id
from @XMLVal.nodes('/row') as t(c)
```

### UPDATE

As you elaborated your XML is coming in completely different shapes. To reach your output target you have to create column names dynamically. If this dynamically, but bound to a closed set, I'd suggest some kind of `PIVOT`. But - in your case - this seems to be completely free. This must be done with dynamic SQL. This means, you create a statement as string (exactly as you would need to type it in order to achieve the correct result. Than you use `EXEC` to execute this command.

One backdraw is, that you cannot use this in *ad-hoc* SQL.

Try this and set the variable `@RowID` to 1 or to 2:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(ID INT IDENTITY,XMLVal XML);
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
 ('<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
   <row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />')
,('<row UWI="123" Xcord="2.4" obj_id="1" err_id="1" /> 
   <row lUWI="122" Xcord="1.4" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />');


DECLARE @RowID INT=2;

DECLARE @columnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') 
        FROM #tbl AS tbl
        CROSS APPLY XMLVal.nodes('row/@*') as t(c) 
        WHERE ID=@RowID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
      ); 

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
  N'SELECT p.*
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
       t.c.value(''local-name(.)'', ''nvarchar(128)'') as [colname],
       t.c.value(''.'', ''nvarchar(128)'') as [value]
    FROM #tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY XMLVal.nodes(''row/@*'') as t(c)
    WHERE ID=' + CAST(@RowID AS NVARCHAR(10)) +
    ') AS tbl
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(value) FOR colname IN(' +  @columnNames + ')
    ) AS p';

    EXEC(@cmd);
GO
DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Comment: Main problem that is attributes are dynamic, names and quantity is not known before execution

Comment: @AlexanderZInchenko, this is a completely different issue which you should have mentioned in your question... Please provide some XML fragments with differing structure. And please give details about *names and quantity is not known*: Completely free? Is there a set of attributes which are sure? Is - at least - each set of rows the same or might this vary *within* one set?

Comment: for example, target table contains two cell. 
1:'<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row link="someLink" DATASOURCE="SomeSystem" obj_id="1" err_id="2" />'
2: '<row UWI="123" Xcord="2.4" obj_id="1" err_id="1" />
<row lUWI="122" Xcord="1.4"obj_id="1" err_id="2" />'

Names and quantity are completely free. I do not need to query different cell same time.

Comment: You are the wizard! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexanderZInchenko not *for some reasons*... You must set the variable `@RowID` to the row you want. You might take away this filter, but then you'd get **all** rows with **all** attributes somehow mixed: